# A way to trace each sqlite query

Tags: logging, sqlite

I've got big and hairy app with sqlite via dbi (from .c) as a backend - plenty of select/insert/update/delete queries.

From looking through documentation I did not found a way to log all the queries issued towards sqlite. I mean of course I could wrap every call to dbi_conn_queryf() into function which does the logging before doing actual request but it feels grossly inefficient.

Is there some hidden option I've missed in dbi sqlite driver? Or maybe there's another library which support per-query tracing for sqlite?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910157/enable-query-logging-in-sqlite-3 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607368/sql-query-logging-for-sqlite, actually all resulting from https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite+query+logging

Comment: I hoped that I could stay at more abstract (dbi-like) level but seems like for sqlite trace api is the only option indeed.